# Anonymous sign in persistence

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I’m creating application that uses Firebase. I want to allow  users to register in application optionally, so user can use my application for year for example and never register.

If user wants he may register (and we will link anonymous login to new account), but that must be an option not required feature.

Now I can use `FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion()`, all working is okay except if session will expire and app will be closed. I can’t sign in again with that UID, so all user’s data is lost.

How can I signIn with same UID or make that anonymous authentication (users hate that requires registration on each application)?

P.S. You may say that I need custom authentication, but as I read for that I need custom authentication server, I have only app and Firebase server.

Comment: The session for your anonymous user should not expire as far as I know. The access token will expire, but will auto-refresh. Most likely there's something wrong in your flow. A [minimal, complete example of how to reproduce your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help with diagnosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Frank van Puffelen posted correct answer:

> The session for your anonymous user should not expire as far as I
>   know. The access token will expire, but will auto-refresh.